# DocumentPicker Extension immediately stopped on clicking on the icon

Tags: ios8

I have created the document picker extension(Both File provide and document picker , with the default implementations)  and when i try to open the extension using the DocumentPickerViewController, its immediately closing the DocumentPickerViewController by  showing the below issue
**plugin com.apple.UIKit.fileprovider.default invalidated.**
I have setup the basic app groups and iCloud entitlement as well, Which are all fine. Even from the documentViewController the default iCloud is working perfectly fine. 
Actually i am testing the extension using the same container application.
If somebody can provide some insight about this behavior, it would be a great help !!

Thanks,
Vishnu

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue, actually the value of `NSExtensionFileProviderDocumentGroup` key was put incorrectly put on the info.plist of the file provider extension by XCode by the time of adding the App group.
Then I compared the files with the NBox sample from Apple and finally figured it out.
So sometimes beware of XCode automatic actions, make a cross check so to save to time.

Comment: This happens  for big file. 70mb +